# how to compare value in 2 dataframe in python and add the value in common variable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dataframe df1 and df2 in python that has same number and name of variables. I want to compare the values in variable A and if the value matches, the corresponding values in C should be added.

```
df1
A      B      C
5717   2      10
6417   2      12
7417   2      11
8417   2      15

df2
A      B      C
5717   2      12
6417   2      16
7417   2      18
8417   2      20

resulting df
A      B      C
5717   2      22
6417   2      28
7417   2      29
8417   2      35
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) + [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df1.set_index(['A','B']).add(df2.set_index(['A','B']), fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
      A  B   C
0  5717  2  22
1  6417  2  28
2  7417  2  29
3  8417  2  35
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `merge`

```
df=df1.merge(df2,on=['A','B'],how='left').fillna(0)

df.assign(C=df['C_x']+df['C_y']).drop(['C_x','C_y'],1)

Out[235]: 
      A  B   C
0  5717  2  22
1  6417  2  28
2  7417  2  29
3  8417  2  35
```